# Server process started by multiprocessing.Manager() makes piped socket not closed immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing

I have following code, server accept net connection, pass it to child to process with `Manager().Queue()`:

```
q = Manager().Queue()

class Server:

    def run(self, host, port):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(1)

        print('parent', os.getpid())

        while True:
            c, _ = s.accept()
            q.put(c)
            c.close()

def handle_request():
    print('child', os.getpid())
    while True:
        c = q.get()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(c.recv(4))
        c.close()

Process(target=handle_request, args=()).start()
Server().run('127.0.0.1', 10000)
```

`close` doesn't work as expected, I think it is because `Manager`'s server process sill have a reference on that socket, `lsof -i` confirmed. How to deal with this? I found there is not a way to close the socket in `Manager` process, `shutdown` could do the trick but not what I want.

Comment: What I can see is that `Server.run` closes the socket right after putting it in a queue. So that socket is the queue is closed from then on.

Comment: @ForceBru nope, child could use it normally.

Comment: What is your question? Why there is another process? Or why the socket doesn't close? And what do you mean by "doesn't close"?

Comment: @bnaecker socket wont be fully released when close called if other process holding a reference, google "close socket refcount".

Comment: The manager's process doesn't have a reference to it once it leaves the queue, I think. I tried this on my machine, and using `netstat` verify that the socket goes into the `CLOSE_WAIT` state. Is that not good enough?

Comment: And if that doesn't happen for you, try adding a `socket.shutdown()` call before the close call, which should close the descriptor regardless of who else owns a reference to the socket.

Comment: @bnaecker `CLOSE_WAIT` exactly means server side not fully closed socket. and shutdown is an option but not what this question wanna address, someone changed my original title, I want know why.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.

I am not sure if this is of any help, but I found your code somewhat odd in the beginning, as sending socket objects using `Manager().Queue()` to another process does not sound like it is supported.  It may be, but sending a file descriptor to another process needs a couple of hoops. I changed your code a bit to do it as I would do it - basically reducing and reconstructing handles.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_handle, rebuild_handle
import socket
import os
from time import sleep

q = Manager().Queue()


class Server:
    def run(self, host, port):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(1)

        print('parent', os.getpid())

        while True:
            c, _ = s.accept()
            foo = reduce_handle(c.fileno())
            q.put(foo)
            c.close()


def handle_request():
    print('child', os.getpid())
    while True:
        bar = q.get()
        sleep(1)
        barbar = rebuild_handle(bar)
        c = socket.fromfd(barbar, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print(c.recv(4))
        c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)

Process(target=handle_request, args=()).start()
Server().run('127.0.0.1', 10000)
```

This does not leave any sockets behind in CLOSE_WAIT at least when I ran it, and it works as I would expect it to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. sending socket object via Queue() is supported in python3 (since 3.3?).

Comment: I managed to get your code working absolutely fine on Ubuntu 16.04 by replacing the `c.close()` in `handle_request()` with `c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`.  No CLOSE_WAIT sockets left behind or anything else out of ordinary.